# Prepend each element to its own parent only

Tags: jquery

I need help with jQuery. I am trying to move one element (author) from left column to right within its parent using `prepend`.
I need each author to be moved inside its own `post` container but right now all author elements moves to every parent container. Can you, please, guide me.
Thank you in advance.

```
<div class="post">
    <div class="col-left">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80">
        <div class="author">Jack</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-right">
        <div class="title">Article-1</div>
        <div class="date">09-21-16</div>
        <div class="intro">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>

<div class="post">
    <div class="col-left">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80">
        <div class="author">Eric</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-right">
        <div class="title">Article-2</div>
        <div class="date">08-21-16</div>
        <div class="intro">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>

<div class="post">
    <div class="col-left">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80">
        <div class="author">Kate</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-right">
        <div class="title">Article-3</div>
        <div class="date">07-21-16</div>
        <div class="intro">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

```js
$(".post .author").prependTo( ".col-right" );
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ujqjgc4k/)

Comment: A fiddle is great, but please ensure you add all relevant code to the question in case the third party site becomes unavailable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour you're seeing is because you're selecting all the `.author` elements and appending them together to all the `.col-right` elements.

Instead you need to loop through the `.author` elements and traverse the DOM to find it's related `.col-right`. Try this:

```
$(".post .author").each(function() {
    var $author = $(this);
    $author.closest('.post').find('.col-right').prepend($author);
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ujqjgc4k/2/)

Comment: Thank you, it works. Can you, please, explain to me what you did on the second line?

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Comment: Just saw your comment edit. The second line gets the closest parent `.post` element to the `.author` in the current iteration of the `each()` loop. From there it finds the `.col-right` within that `.post` and prepends the author to it. If you want to know more about the functions used, check our the jQuery docs: http://api.jquery.com

Answer (score 0):

Loop through each author class from left column and then use prependTo

```
$(".author").each(function (a, b) {       
      $(b).prependTo($(b).closest('.post').find('>.col-right'));  
});
```

```js
$(".author").each(function (a, b) {       
          $(b).prependTo($(b).closest('.post').find('>.col-right'));  
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.col-left {
  width:20%;
  float:left;
 }
 .col-right {
   width:80%;
   float:left;
 }
.post {
  border:1px solid grey;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.date {
  font-size: 10px;
  color: grey;
}
.author {
  color: red;
}
  </style>
<div class="post">
 <div class="col-left">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80">
  <div class="author">Jack</div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-right">
  <div class="title">Article-1</div>
  <div class="date">09-21-16</div>
  <div class="intro">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
 </div>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>

<div class="post">
 <div class="col-left">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80">
  <div class="author">Eric</div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-right">
  <div class="title">Article-2</div>
  <div class="date">08-21-16</div>
  <div class="intro">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
 </div>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>

<div class="post">
 <div class="col-left">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80">
  <div class="author">Kate</div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-right">
  <div class="title">Article-3</div>
  <div class="date">07-21-16</div>
  <div class="intro">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
 </div>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```